# LikesControler for a Post

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I have this controller that I call via Ajax, where I update the likes of a post.

I have two methods in the user model:

- `already_like_post?`: Where I pass the posted ID and return true or false if the post is already liked.
- `dislike_post`: Delete the user like for given post.

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
    def create
        if !current_user.already_liked_post? params[:post_id]
            like = Like. new user: current_user, post_id: params[:post_id]
            if !like.save
                render json: like.errors
            end
        else
           current_user.dislike_post params[:post_id]
        end
        amount_of_likes = Post.find(params[:post_id]).likes.count
        render json:{status:"success",likes: amount_of_likes}
    end
end
```

These are the methods in the user model:

```
def already_liked_post?(post_id)
    self.likes.where(post_id: post_id).size == 1
end

def dislike_post(post_id)
    self.likes.find_by(post_id: post_id).destroy
end
```

Can you give a review of this? I don't know if this looks good or if it is the Rails way.

Comment: How do you record dislikes, I believe you also have a Dislike model? or keep it under the Like model but having an attribute to determine whether it was "liked" or "disliked"(bloody).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- Use 2-space indentation.
- Move all the logic to the model.
- DB deletes can also fail.
- No need for `self.`
- If you use `object` instead of `object_id` as argument, code is usually more declarative.
- In case of error, you are performing a double render.

I'd write:

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    if current_user.toggle_like(post)
      render(json: {status: "success", likes: post.likes.count})
    else
      render(json: {status: "error"}, status: :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Model
  # Toggle like for post. Returns boolean with the status of the operation.
  def toggle_like(post)
    likes_for_post = likes.where(post_id: post.id)

    if likes_for_post.exists?
      likes_for_post.destroy_all.all?(&:destroyed?)
    else
      likes.new(post: post).save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I really liked that I even did the refactoring.

Two notes:
1. The method **exist?**, its named **exists?**.
2. It's throwed an error when I called the destroy method instead I had to use the **destroy_all** method.

Thanks.

Comment: You are spot-on on both notes, updated.

Comment: @Nivla: I've refactored `toggle_like` to make sure it returns a meaningful boolean.

Comment: Great, what means `.all?(&:destroyed?)`, the current record already destroyed?

Comment: Yes, it makes sure all the `Like` objects (usually, just one), have been destroyed. "destroy" may not suceed (it returns false) for example if a before_destroy callbacks stops it.

Answer (score 2):

Architecturally this looks fine. The database end of might need some tweaking, however.

```
amount_of_likes = Post.find(params[:post_id]).likes.count
```

This results in two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ...
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE post_id = ...
```

This will load the `Post`, then do a `count(*)` on the `likes` relation. Why not get the count by the `Like` model instead:

```
amount_of_likes = Like.where(user_id: current_user.id).count
```

(assuming the `Like` and `User` models are related in that way)

This does a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE user_id = ...` which would avoid loading the `Post` object.

The only other thing I would recommend is to return a `422` HTTP response code if the Like failed to save:

```
    if !like.save
        render json: like.errors, status: 422
    end
else
    ...
end
...
render json: { likes: amount_of_likes }
```

This would eliminate the need for a "status" flag. Switching the HTTP response code would prevent this route in your application from being used as a JSONP request, but if it's just normal same-domain AJAX or cross-domain AJAX with the proper permissions in place, then the status code would be ideal.

The error handler in JavaScript on the client would handle the validation errors.

Comment: According to a deleted answer I converted to a comment on the question: You forgot to add post_id on the where query. `def already_liked_post?(post_id)
    Like.where(user_id: current_user.id, post_id: params[:post_id]).count > 0
   end` (I personally don't know if this is correct or not)